# JavaScript is not printing my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I have this function:

```
function suggestSell() {
    var sellValue = document.getElementById('sellValue');
    var btcVol = document.getElementById('btcVol');
    var grossSell = btcVol * sellValue ;
    var sellFee = grossSell * .006;
    var sellOff = grossSell - sellFee;
    document.write('<p>sellValue: ' + sellValue.innerHTML +
                   '<br> btcVol: ' + btcVol.innerHTML +
                   '<br> grossSell: ' + grossSell +
                   '<br> sellFee: ' + sellFee +
                   '<br> sellOff: ' + sellOff +
                   '<br></p>');  
}
```

that i call like this:

```
<script>suggestSell();</script>
```

But it displays this in the browser.

> 1156.161.42053359undefinedundefinedundefined

Answer (score 2):

```
var sellValue = document.getElementById('sellValue');
```

selects the node. You probably need the `value`

```
var sellValue = document.getElementById('sellValue').value;
```

Same thing for `btcVol`

```
var btcVol = document.getElementById('btcVol').value;
```

If you do make this change, note that `sellValue.innerHTML` and `btcVol.innerHTML` should be changed appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However I stilol get the same result. this is what i changed it to
`function suggestSell()
  {
  var sellValue = document.getElementById('sellValue').value;
  var btcVol = document.getElementById('btcVol').value;
  var grossSell = btcVol * sellValue ;
  var sellFee = grossSell * .006;
  var sellOff = grossSell - sellFee;
  document.write('<p>sellValue: ' + sellValue.value + '<br> btcVol: ' + btcVol.value + '<br> grossSell: ' + grossSell + '<br> sellFee: ' + sellFee + '<br> sellOff: ' + sellOff + '<br></p>');  
  }`

Comment: There were a few more minor issues. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VBsG2/ I have tried to address the issues.